# how to add an expression to see a range of memory using watch window in eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

The mysql has the following code:
table->file->ha_write_row(table->record[0]))

where table->record[0] is a buffer whose size is determined by another variable reclength. Now I know the reclength, see it's 203. And I want to see the value (table->record[0])[0..202], which means from the first byte to the last byte. If I just put (table->record[0]) in the watch, it only display several chars as there are many 0 inside table->record[0], say it could be like "xxx\\0\\0\\0yyy...",  In this case, eclipse only show "xxx" in the watch window as it thinks "xxx\0" is the complete string terminated by "\\0", but actually I want to see more buffer value.  So I used (table->record[0])[i] in the watch, i is 0 , 1, 2 .., but that's boring, is there any good way to see all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the gdb syntax for printing array values, for array whose first element is pointed to by pointer `p`, use:

```
p@100
```

To see first 100 elements. In your case, edit your watch expression (left click -> `Edit Watch Expression`)  to:

```
table->record@100
```

You didn't mention the type of `table->record` --- I am assuming it holds the pointer (and not the pointer-to-pointer).

And btw, you can cast your pointer to any data type, exactly as in a gdb console.